# Error starting process java.exe

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Full error is as below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.>
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe''

People seem to have problems with java 'finishing with non-zero exit value...', but I cannot find any answers for my problem above.

I'm doing a Gradle build on Android Studio v2.3.1
Gradle version - 3.3

My build.gradle file is like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
        jackInProcess false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/index.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    ...
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile files('libs/mypackage-super.jar')
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jack is no longer needed for Java 8 so try removing it for starters https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Comment: That's only if I upgrade to using studio version 2.4 right? I use 2.3, and I am not in a position to upgrade. Is there any particular reason why the error I got can occur?

Comment: If you don't have real reason to use java 8, downsize java (delete jack and compile options) and try build it. Using java 8 this way is very problematic because it's sort of workaround. Personally I also had problem with one library that required java 8, but I gave it up at the end because it was impossible to sort it out to build gradle as you can see from several other threads on stackoverflow dating before this latest update that i linked in previous comment.